# How to make jsonp request in Angular2 without using JSONP_CALLBACK

Tags: angular, jsonp

I'm trying to make JSONP request to a website which I do not own. Their callback name will not change regardless what I put in the callback= field. Is there any way to set a custom callback name in Angular2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Since Angular doesn't support a custom callback name for JSONP endpoints yet (unless I didn't do my research well).

There's this trick back from the old day of Vanilla JS

You can create a custom function somewhere in a service or component to manually load your JSONP and provide a custom callback name.

```
getJSONP(uri, callbackName) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {

      let id = '_' + Math.round(10000 * Math.random());

      window[callbackName] = (data) => {
          delete window[callbackName];
          let ele = document.getElementById(id);
          ele.parentNode.removeChild(ele);
          resolve(data);
      }

      let src = uri + '&callback=' + callbackName;

      let script = document.createElement('script');
      script.src = src;
      script.id = id;
      script.addEventListener('error', reject);
      document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
    })
  }
```

and call it from your component or service

```
this.getJSONP(JSONPUri, 'myCustomCallbackName').then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
})
```

Basically this will still create a script tag and callback function in the head and delete it when done loading the JSONP so you can adapt it for your scenario.

Comment: I tried your code and it works perfectly! How does this code work? I don't even see you making any http request...

Comment: JSONP is not loaded using XMLHttpRequest. It's loaded using a normal script tag